# @cacheable method is always executed and ingoing timeToLiveSeconds

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

@cacheable method is always executed and ingoing timeToLiveSeconds

cache-service.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ehcache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring
     http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd">
    <ehcache:annotation-driven create-missing-caches="true" cache-manager="cacheManager" />
    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="shared" value="true" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="cacheKeyGenerator" class="com.test.StringArgumentCacheKeyGenerator" />
</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <spring.framework.version>5.1.6.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.9.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <spring.integration.version>5.1.4.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>
</properties>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.ehcache-spring-annotations</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-spring-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

ehcache.xml

```
<cache name="myList" 
        overflowToDisk="false"  statistics="true"
        eternal="false"
        maxElementsInMemory="10000"
        timeToIdleSeconds="0"
        timeToLiveSeconds="300"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />
```

Java class: The getDepartmentsList() is called everytime I visit the page that displays the department.
I added system out "I am getting the dept" to debug.
The timeToLiveSeconds set to 5 min. So I was hoping if I refresh the page within 5 min, I will not see print statement "I am getting the dept".

```
  public class MyClass
  {
    @Cacheable(cacheName = "myList", keyGeneratorName = "cacheKeyGenerator" )
    public final Map<String, String> getDepartmentsList(String userid) {
        System.out.println("I am getting the dept");
        Map<String, String> deptMap = myService.getAuthorizedDept(userid);
        return deptMap;
    }
 }
```

I am new to spring ehcache and debugging this is not easy. The only way I was able to troubleshoot this by adding system.out.  I will appreciate any help/suggestions on how to fix this. Thank you

Update: based on the comments I updated the java class and I am seeing the following:

```
  public class MyClass
  {
  
    public final Map<String, String> getDepartmentsList(String userid) {
        System.out.println("I am getting the dept" );
        Map<String, String> deptMap = myService.getAuthorizedDept(userid);
        return deptMap;
    }
 }

@Service 
public class Myservice
{
@Cacheable(cacheName = "myList", keyGeneratorName = "cacheKeyGenerator" )
    public Map<String, String> getDepartmentsList(String userid){
    }
}
```

- With updated code as suggested, the method does not call that often but do get calls before the 5 min up. I was just refreshing the browser.
- I am getting the dept 2020/09/30 19:53:43
- I am getting the dept 2020/09/30 19:55:47

based on above, it refreshed in 2 min

- I am getting the dept 2020/09/30 20:10:56
- I am getting the dept 2020/09/30 20:12:57

based on above, it refreshed in 2 min but time is set to 5 min (    timeToLiveSeconds="300")

- Also, If I the close the browser session, it calls the method regardless of if time has expired or not. Very confuse as if the cache is browser based or it is caching on the server. Sorry if my questions are very basic.

Thank you all for your comments so far.

Comment: Is MyClass a Spring bean? Are you invoking the cacheable method from another Spring bean or from another method in the same class?

Comment: Why are you using Spring XML config in 2020? Is that something you found online?

Comment: Ditch the google cache stuff and use the Spring caching. You are currently configuring the google caching annotions but are using the Spring implementation. That is obviously not going to work. So remove the google stuff and use the Spring stuff.

Comment: For spring configuration instead of google, can you please give me example of pom.xml as to which dependency to include. I guessing if I use the spring instead of google, my java implementation won't change.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First You should make MyClass as a Bean with @Component or @Service.
Then you invoke method getDepartmentsList()  in another spring object for example, Controller or RestController. If you invoke the method in same class, cache will not be effective.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. With updated code as suggested, the method does not call that often but do get calls before the 5 min up. I was just refreshing the browser.
I am getting the dept 2020/09/30 19:53:43
I am getting the dept 2020/09/30 19:55:47 I have added the updated code on this post after your suggestions.